# I need a way/function that sets the cursor to the first line

Tags: c++, winapi

I was trying to print a transaction for my project, but I wanted to set the cursor back to the first line so as to be able to make it work better. I don't want to use `system("cls")` because it deletes all the page, and then the transaction will not look cool.

I tried `cout<<string(200,'\b');` and `cout<<string(200,'\r');`

[image: the one I want to make transaction to]

Comment: This can be OS specific.  Standard `c++` does not have this ability. It can be a function of the terminal you are using. The usual recommendation is to use the `ncurses` library. On windows the `winapi` has console functions you can also use or if your terminal has ansi escape sequences those work on many different systems.

Comment: While Standard C++ has no immediate support for cursor positioning, it also doesn't actively object to using [Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) (which, incidentally, support cursor positioning).

Comment: BTW, I added the winapi tag after seeing the self-answer. The question appears to be about only the windows api and not another OS like linux or macOS.

Answer (score 1):

I could use the `SetConsoleCursorPosition()` function in the `windows.h` header, like this:

```
COORD coor;
coor.X = 0;//where x should be
coor.Y = 0;//where y should be
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coor);//where it should set the cursor back
```

Comment: I think what @IInspectable suggests is what MS recommend, moving forwards.